# MongoDB projecting an entire subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've got a bunch of documents like this in my collection.

```
{
"success": true,
"timestamp": 1519296206,
"base": "EUR",
"date": "2018-07-04",
"rates": {
    "AUD": 1.566015,
    "CAD": 1.560132,
    "CHF": 1.154727,
    "CNY": 7.827874,
    "GBP": 0.882047,
    "JPY": 132.360679,
    "USD": 1.23396,
  }
}
```

I would like to only get `date` and the entire `rates` subdocument like below. I know I could add `rates.AUD`, `rates.CAD` etc. to the projection but that would make the projection extremely big and just unbearable to read and hard to maintain as a new field (or currency in this case) might get added in the future.

```
{
"date": "2018-07-04",
"rates": {
    "AUD": 1.566015,
    "CAD": 1.560132,
    "CHF": 1.154727,
    "CNY": 7.827874,
    "GBP": 0.882047,
    "JPY": 132.360679,
    "USD": 1.23396,
  }
}
```

Is there any projection similar to  `{date: 1, "rates.*". 1}` that works like described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
db.col.aggregate([ {
    $project: {
        date: 1,
        rates: 1
    }
}])
```

Comment: Using `db.collection.find()` this gives me MongoError code 2.

Comment: Try with `db.collection.aggregate()`